# Column expression translation

Tags: ssis-2019

This is an excel condition but I want to be written out in the derived column expression field

=IF(Z2<0,"Late",(IF(AND(Z2>-1,Z2<16),"0-15 Days",(IF(AND(Z2>15,Z2<31),"15-30 Days",(IF(Z2>30,"30+Days",Z2)))))))

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression.

Comment: what do you mean by case expression